# Why doesn't my view update?

Tags: angular

On the code below, as you can see, I subscribe to an observable and on the callback I set status to the value of `result`. This is used on an *ngIf on the view. Fact is, even when true is returned, the view is not updated.

```
  export class AppComponent {

  private status;

  constructor (private proxyService: ProxyService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    //setInterval(()=>console.log(this.isInjected),1000);
    this.proxyService.someObservable.subscribe((result)=>{
      this.status = result;
      console.log(result);
    });
  }

}
```

Now, you might notice the commented line. While debugging I added it, and the weird thing is it makes the view update. Any ideas why?

For reference, that is my view:

```
  <div *ngIf="status">
    <app-userlane-inject></app-userlane-inject>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!status">
    <span>Status is false.</span>
  </div>
{{status}}
```

The child component is never rendered, and the string interpolation remains false even when console logs true (except if the interval is there, then it works).

Here is what the service does in broad terms:

```
var mySubject= new BehaviorSubject(false);


@Injectable()
export class ProxyService {
  public someObservable= mySubject.asObservable();


//Kinda deep callback tree, then finally
  mySubject.next(true)

}
```

---

Just some extra info to put answers into context: the deep callback chain I mentioned above goes completely out of angular (this was an extension, and the call chain included sending a message to the content script, then to the page, and all the way back).
That is why angular zone needs to be called into action again.
I didn't know that was the cause, and that is why I didn't include that on my initial question.

Comment: You don't need `var me = this;`. Just use `this.status = result;`

Comment: What is `ProxyService`? Can you share some code?

Comment: What is the output from console.log(result);

Comment: Output is true, that's the thing

Comment: I'll try without `me`, but I think it was getting the wrong `this` before.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yeah using `me` wans't necessary, but not the cause of the problem...

Comment: You can use the chrome plug-in augury, https://augury.angular.io/, this will allow you to view your data in your app while running (in dev mode).  So you can see what the true status of your data is.  Handy for debugging

Comment: That's handy @jason.kaisersmith, thanks. That's what I was trying to do when I added the interval console log, but that FIXED the problem lol. Probably a ngZone thing, which I don't know anything about.

Comment: Why are you initializing `mySubject` outside of `ProxyService`? Have you tried inside?

Comment: @RSinohara have you tried?

Comment: I've done it like this for a while, reasons are gone now. But I moved it inside and still no go. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: NgZone worked, I had no knowledge of it :)

Comment: Now that I know @GünterZöchbauer solution works, I'm surprised this question hasn't been asked before. Maybe we can make it more accessible/search friendly (although the title seems good).

Comment: There are dozens of questions where `zone.run()` is suggested. Some APIs are not covered and there it makes sense. The problem with your question is that it doesn't contain code where it's obvious it is required, because `Observable` usually just works, but if the event is emitted outside Angulars zone, then `Observable` can't fix it on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you initialize `mySubject` outside the class, it will run outside Angulars zone, which will prevent Angular to recognize events and therefore won't run change detection.

```
@Injectable()
export class ProxyService {
  private mySubject= new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public someObservable= this.mySubject.asObservable();


//Kinda deep callback tree, then finally
  this.mySubject.next(true)
}
```

**update**

You can use

```
  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}
```

```
  this.zone.run(()=> this.mySubject.next(true));
```

but if this solves your problem there is probably something wrong in the call chain where some event or callback is not happening inside Angulars zone.

Comment: Just tried this, it makes sense. But no fix. Maybe my callback tree takes execution away from ngZone (it definitely might)? I'll try ngZone.run.

Comment: `this.ngZone.run(()=>this.isInjected = result);` Solved it. So it's not the observable, it was the call tree before `.next` taking it away from the zone. Your answer led me to it, if you update with the fix, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer. You you locate where the root cause was?

Comment: Well yes... That call goes to content script via tabs.sendMessage, then to the page via dom event, then back the same path... so not surprised that it leaves the zone. That solution worked, and is a must know for extension development.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display observables is to create a dumb components to display them.

Example:

If `this.status` is an observable

Create a dumb component to display it.

```
//dumb component to display status

   @Component({
      selector: 'dumb-display-comp',
      template: '{{ status }}'  
    })
    export class DumbDisplayComp {
        @Input() status: any;
    }
```

Now use you dumb component in the parent component and send as input the observable with the async pipe.

Your parent template using the dumb component

```
<dumb-display-comp [status]="status | async" ></dumb-display-comp>
```

Your app should be filled with dumb components to declutter your main ones.
Just my two cents.